# this.http.post is not working in ionic 3 even it doesn't show any errors

Tags: api, ionic-framework

am new to ionic, 
am just tying to create login page using API. 
But it's nothing doing

```
export class RemoteserviceProvider {
headers = new Headers( { 'X-API-KEY' : '578432679127342398465' }); 
 constructor(public http: Http) {
console.log('Hello RemoteserviceProvider Provider');
}

 login(credentials) {
  console.log(credentials);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.http.post('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', credentials,{headers})
    .subscribe(res => {
      resolve(res.json());
    }, (err) => {
      reject(err);
    });
    console.log(err);
   });
   }
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a syntax error to me. Try changing `this.http.post('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', credentials,{headers})` to `this.http.post('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', credentials,{headers: headers})`.

Comment: it doesn't working, i think this.http.post is not access that API
My console nothing show any error

Comment: check the network tab to see if the api call goes or not

Comment: what is the format of the credentials you're sending with the post call

Comment: {mobile: "xxxxxxxxxx", password: "xxxxxx"}
like this i want to pass my credentials into API

Comment: have you tried setting the content-type header like the above user has suggested

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171080/discussion-between-meena-and-saksham-gupta).

Answer (score 0):

You have to set 'content-type' attribute in the header to tell the api what kind of data is being passed.

```
  import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

  let headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  headers.set('X-API-KEY' : '578432679127342398465');
```

And then in the api call, you should assign the headers variable to the headers attribute

```
  this.http.post('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', credentials,{headers: headers})
```